# iOS Detect Touch on Custom Map Image to Select Irregular Shaped Region

Tags: ios

I have a *png* image of a country's map showing its regions.

I want to detect touch and select (uniquely identify) any irregular shaped region from map and perform some activity for selected region. I also want to show/display selection of region while tapping on it (either by highlighting region's image or showing a line on his boundary).

Please tell me the best way to achieve this. `MKMapView` won't help as i don't want to use `Apple/Google maps.`

Comment: Did you manage to achieve your goal? I'm facing a similar task.

Comment: Nope, i didn't get the answer. Initially i used a bitmap image of map with every region having unique RGB/Hex color code and i was able to identify region based on color selection but i couldn't show the selected region. Then requirements of my app changed and i integrated Google maps.